# Unable to load image thumbnail using Dropbox v2 API and HTTP GET

Tags: get, dropbox-api, url-parameters

Dropbox v2 API documentation states the following:

```
For compatibility with web browsers, content-style endpoints
can also be used with HTTP GET requests. In this case,
Dropbox-Api-Arg and Authorization query parameters can be
used as a replacement for those headers.
```

When I try constructing the URL and getting a thumbnail, when getting it with wget I get back `400 Bad Request`. Trying it in Chrome, I get back ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE, response is not visible in Developer Tools.

This is my URL (sensitive data edited), after URL encoding:

https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail?Authorization=Bearer%20<alphanumeric_access_token>&Dropbox-API-Arg=%7B%22path%22%3A%22id%3A<alphanumeric_id>%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22w128h128%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22jpeg%22%7D

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204418756-Using-V2-HTTP-content-style-endpoints-with-GET ]

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fish it out using cURL which was kind enough to print out the HTTP response.

The correct parameters to use are (case-sensitive) `authorization` and `arg`